# HP laptop doesn't power up

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply

I am kindly asking for your help. I have an HP DV7T-6C00 laptop which doesn't power up at all. I have read various forum threads and they did not solve my problem that's why I'm opening a new one.

It started about two weeks ago, when it didn't want to wake up from sleeping, only after removing battery and plugging the charger in. It seemed odd, so I did backup from everything. Ever since then it does not power up at all.

When I plug the charger in (without battery), the charger indicator light is on with a steady white. If battery is in the result the same. If I have the battery disconnected from the laptop for a while, the light is orange (meaning that it's charging) and it becomes white (meaning that it's fully charged).

I tried various solutions to solve the problem, including the following:
- disconnecting every external device
- power up with only battery,
- power up without battery but with charger,
- hard reset (for 15 sec, 30 sec, 2 mins holding the power button),
- removing one RAM module, another and both,
- removing hard drive,
- removing optical drive,
- checking ZIF connectors,
- holding the power button for 15 sec.

No fan sound, no beep sounds, no emergency LEDs (Caps Lock and Num Lock), nothing except for the charger indicator light. Also, I can feel the power button is working.

I happen to have a multimeter and with that I was able to exclude the charger as a possible cause since its voltage is within norm.

I have two guesses: the motherboard and the CPU. Unfortunately I have no replacing capabilities to check them without being sure which is the cause.

The challenge is open for everyone, thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: There is an internal power regulator that could be bad.  Laptops have no "user-serviceable" parts.  Virtually everything is on the systemboard, so pretty much anything that goes wrong, the solution is to replace the systemboard.

Comment: @fixer1234
But how can I be sure about that its not the CPU? Because without propeply working CPU it wouldn't boot up, would it?

Comment: There are a number of things it could be, including the CPU.  I don't know specifically about your laptop but on most, they save space and weight by soldering everything, sometimes even the RAM.  For most laptops, the fix for almost any failure is replacing the systemboard.  If your CPU is removable and you have a tester or another systemboard, you could check it.  Even most service facilities can't test systemboards.  They replace them and the old ones go to a refurbisher with the right equipment.  If reparable, they come back as replacement parts.

Comment: Well. I thought it won't be solved, but life is funny (and it still isn't). I've tried accidentally with another (a third one which has almost the same voltage but half Amper) charger - it turned on! It did even restart with a Ctrl+Alt+Del combo. However, after I turned it off (with the power button, because no HDD in it), it did not want to power up again.
Somehow, I managed to find a way with hard resetting, changing adapter and taking the battery out and putting back it, to power it up. I played it three times.
Now, I am a bit confused and awaiting for your wisdom and advice. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone to have a chance at diagnosing this kind of problem from afar, you really need to create a very structured diagnostic history: I did this and this happened; I did that and that happened, along with all of the pertinent details.  I would recommend rewriting the question with all of the available information to date in a very organized format.  That will also refresh it in the active questions list and get more eyes on the problem.

Comment: I had to give back the another charger, and suddenly, now it powers up with its own charger. Still can't repower after turning it off. I am puzzled...

Comment: Trying to figure out erratic problems can give you brain damage.  You're right there and can try different things and see what happens.  Imagine how hard it is for someone with nothing to go on but what you describe.  Plus every new diagnostic step requires someone suggesting something to try, you're doing it, then updating the information, so it can take forever to get to the root of the problem.  Tough problems can be a lot easier to solve hands on.  But if you don't have someone locally, update your question as described in my previous comment.

Comment: Just a few more ideas. Try to measure the charger's voltage while it is plugged into the laptop. I suppose you measured it on the cable. And another (remote) possibility: check if the 'closed' detector isn't failing (they're normally magnetic - hard to fail). Also check the power socket on the board. Repeated plugging in/out may have broken the soldering.